# Why hyphen sign is used as prefix for AppDelegate methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i know the hyphen sign before the methods indicates the method is an instance method but there are no instances created for the methods in the AppDelegate.m file.So what kind of method are they then? What does the Hyphen sign indicate here?

help me understand this. i am new to objective c and xcode

Comment: It's the app DELEGATE. Are you familiar with delegate pattern? Did you check the implementation of the  `main.m`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the name implies, it's a delegate object and delegates are class instances that implement a `@protocol` (the [`UIApplicationDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIApplicationDelegate) protocol, in this case).

The [`UIApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/) instance will call whatever delegate methods have been defined by you, the coder.

Understanding the delegate pattern is very important when coding for Cocoa/Cocoa Touch.

Comment: thank you. but why the '-' sign, if it is a class instance then why not a '+' sign to prefix those method, in this case:                                                                   [-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application]

Comment: @NakulBharadwaj Because it's a class *instance*.  It's an instance of a class.